# <mx:HTML/> content looks crusty when resized

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml, flex4

I've got HTML component as part of a datagroup itemrenderer which I need to resize the content of (there are lots of them).

This works quite well but the content looks really crusty. No font antialiasing. Even at 50% looks crusty.

I've considered generating thumbnails bitmaps on load 'complete', but that would be my last resort.

```
<mx:HTML location="{uri}" width="900" height="660" scaleX=".25" scaleY=".25" />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

nic

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the HTML page. If you've designed the page, make sure that you have tested the page on various sizes (by resizing). Flex's mx:HTML simply renders what is in the HTML page.

A good HTML design includes ordering all page elements inside a table (with invisible borders) so that even when the page is resized, the elements won't get crusty.

Thanks,

Nirmal

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to reduce size by changing width and height of mx:HTML and keep scaleX and scaleY equal to 1 (even if you parent has scale < 1, then your mx:HTML shall have scale = 1/parent.scale).

In your example it will be like that:

`<mx:HTML location="{uri}" width="{900*0.25}" height="{660*0.25}" scaleX="1" scaleY="1" />`